# djangotables2 shows bullets near pagenumbers

Tags: html, django, django-tables2

I am new to django-tables2 and was trying out few things. I followed the django-tables2 tutorial of using data from model directly without creating tables with another dataset. However bullets appear near the page numbers area. How do I remove the bullet points?

[Screenshot of the bottom of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCsCZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use the default `table.html` template without the styling also suggested in the tutorial:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css' %}" />
```

You also need to add a css class 'paleblue' to the `<table>`'s class attribute, which you can do by creating the table rather than passing a queryset to your context:

```
class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        # add class="paleblue" to <table> tag
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}

def people(request):
    table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'people.html', {'table': table})
```

(this is also described in the tutorial)

You could remove the bullets by either using that stylesheet or using your own custom stylesheet with something like this:

```
table + ul.pagination > li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

but you might also want to position the `<li>'s` horizontally among some other style fixes.

Comment: I am not familiar working with css. But I have this ``{% load static %}`` and ``<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css' %}" />``  in my html.

Comment: Hmm, that should do the trick. Is it also present in the rendered HTML?

Comment: Hmm, I see the paleblue css class is not added by default to the table generated in the tutorial, I'll update my answer to explain how to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying using data from model directly without creating tables. I saw that customisation can be done if a table is created. So the list structure for pagination cannot be changed without customization?

Comment: What you could do is use a custom template and either set DJANGO_TABLES2_TEMPLATE to it's full path, or use the second argument of the template tag to render the table with that specific template.